# ExtJS 3.4.1 Grid Panel remove header offset

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs, gridpanel

How do I remove header offset of a grid panel? Right now the header div automatically has `"x-grid3-header-offset" {padding-left:1px;text-align:left}` as its class so the content of each row will be right shifted as the browser get expanded. It looks something like this -

```
                 table1                    -----> table header
col1     col2    col3    col4   col5        ----->column headers
 cell1    cell2   cell3   cell4   cell5      ----->cells of first row
 cell1    cell2   cell3   cell4   cell5      ----->cells of second row
```

how do I remove this class from the div so the table cells will look normal like this?

```
                 table1                    -----> table header
col1     col2    col3    col4    col5        ----->column headers
cell1    cell2   cell3   cell4   cell5      ----->cells of first row
cell1    cell2   cell3   cell4   cell5      ----->cells of second row
```

Comment: Please make a fiddle for us to see; I suspect wrong column definitions or a ExtJS bug.

Answer (score 1):

```
renderer:function(val,cell){
            cell.align='right';
            return val;
        }
```

use a renderer function on your column, here is a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1lvg).

More about column renderer [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.column.Column.html#cfg-renderer).

Comment: I just updated the description could you take a look